# use labels in cox regression results

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

Trying to add labels to variable name to make it more coherent when displaying results
The following

```
library(survival)
data(lung)
Hmisc::label(lung$sex) <- "Gender"
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~
    as.factor(sex) 
                 , data = lung)
res.cox
```

produces this result:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ as.factor(sex), data = lung)

                   coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z       p
as.factor(sex)2 -0.5310    0.5880   0.1672 -3.176 0.00149

Likelihood ratio test=10.63  on 1 df, p=0.001111
n= 228, number of events= 165
```

I would like to change `as.factor(sex)2` into `Gender = 2`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just use the `factor` command:

```
lung$Gender <- factor(lung$sex, labels=c(" = 1"," = 2"))
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Gender, data = lung)
res.cox
```

---

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ Gender, data = lung)

               coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z       p
Gender = 2 -0.5310    0.5880   0.1672 -3.176 0.00149

Likelihood ratio test=10.63  on 1 df, p=0.001111
n= 228, number of events= 165
```

Comment: This is a great idea but it does not solve for a use case when I want to use specific factor level in cox regression.

for example:
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ as.factor(sex == 2) , data = lung)

Comment: Then change your question so that it is clearer. As it stands, both answers solve your stated question perfectly. Oh, the other guy deleted his answer. :|